# How do I have centered equations on right case?

Tags: math-mode, cases

[image: Here is an example of what I want to achieve.]

Here is an example of what I want to achieve. I have tried below but the equations won't center automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{rcases}
    p \\
    p \rightarrow r \\
    q \rightarrow \neg r
  \end{rcases}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

I want automatic centering.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the `array` environment in your equation or inline math would be the easiest solution I suppose. It also doesn't really require a `gather*`or `gathered`environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \left.
        \begin{array}{c}
            p \\
            p \rightarrow r \\
            q \rightarrow \neg r \\
        \end{array}
        \right\}
        \Rightarrow
        \neg q
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a difference between using `array` and `gathered`: with the latter, `\displaystyle` is used for every line.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `gathered` environment inside `equation`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{gathered}
    p \\
    p \rightarrow r \\
    q \rightarrow \neg r
\end{gathered}
\right\rbrace
\quad\Rightarrow\quad\neg q
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can revert to a classical `array` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \left.
  \begin{array}{c}
    p \\
    p \rightarrow r \\
    q \rightarrow \neg r
  \end{array}
  \right\rbrace
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Never use `gather*` as a substitute for `equation*`.

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward with a stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \left.\Centerstack{
    p \\
    p \rightarrow r \\
    q \rightarrow \neg r
  }\right\}
\Rightarrow \neg q
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]